# How to determine domain for polar functions?

Tags: polar-coordinates

For a given polar function, how do I determine the exact domain such that I only get the specific petals I want? For instance, I typed in some domains for this particular polar function by setting when $\sin x = 0$, the solving for my $\theta$ for those intervals when the sine function is 0. For instance, the function:

$$r=\sin (4\theta +1.35)$$
$$\sin x=0, x=0,\pi, 2\pi, 3\pi,....$$
$$4\theta+1.35=n\pi, n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

[image]

I cannot seem to get consecutive petals (and instead get petals appearing on random quadrants) even though the domain of where the sine function is equal to zero is consecutive ($0,\pi,2\pi,...$). So I was wondering, how do I specifically get the parts of the petal that I want ? is there a way of specifically setting the domain such that this can occur ?

Comment: Not a full answer, but in case you didn't know, what's happening is that $r$ is going negative, and so your point is popping over to the other side. If you had, say, 6 consecutive regions, numbered 1 2 3 4 5 6, you would see them appearing (going counter clockwise) in the order 1 3 5 2 4 6.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on this further please?

Comment: You're trying to understand which "petals' correspond to which ranges of values, yes? This would be so much easier face to face, but here's my suggestion: If you could see the curve being drawn as $\theta$ increases you would understand. But I can't get Desmos to animate that. So instead, use a single instance of your equation, and set the range to 0 -> 0.1. Then bump it up by 0.1 by editing the upper value, and notice where the petals go as the upper range goes 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 .... 6.3. Also, I think I was wrong with 1 3 5 2 4 6, but you should be able to write the patter that does show up.